# How do I take a webcam snapshot picture in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

Using Flex, what is the recommended way of taking a webcam snapshot picture?

Something along the lines of:

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var image:Image = /* magic goes here */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to create a Video object in which you attach the camera :

```
var video:Video = new Video(320,240);
video.attachCamera(camera);
addChild(video);
```

Then create an instance of a BitmapData with the same size as your video object and draw in it the video object.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width,video.height);
bitmapData.draw(video);
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to solve this problem.

There is a good opensource project you can see.

Userbooth
http://www.userbooth.com/